# How to initialize OnFragmentInteractionListener without onAttach(Context context) for use with FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to make my app (which uses com.firebase.ui and com.firebase.ui.auth) work on an old api level 15 (4.0.4) device.  First I use the manifest tag:

```
 <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui, com.firebase.ui.auth"/>
```

but then I found that on the old device the onAttach(Context...) method was not getting called.
So I read some posts about it and this is what I came up with based on what I read:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach Activity 1A "  );
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            setmListener(activity );
        }

    }

    private void setmListener(Context context){
        Log.d(TAG, "setmListener 1  "  );
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach Context 1 "  );
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            setmListener(context);
        }
    }
```

When the code runs on the old api 15 device the onAttach(Context context) method does not get called just the onAttach(Activity activity) method (same for an emulator running Lollipop).

```
 D/StSt_MaxWListFrag: onAttach Activity 1A 
 D/StSt_MaxWListFrag: setmListener 1
```

But on the device with M both methods run but the setmListener only gets called once as expected:

```
D/StSt_MaxWListFrag: onAttach Context 1 
D/StSt_MaxWListFrag: onAttach Activity 1A 
D/StSt_MaxWListFrag: setmListener 1
```

So - so far it seems to be working,  no problems so far.   I am just wondering if there is something I am missing here - is this approach going to cause me headaches down the road or is it bad practise - maybe inefficient? 
Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)), `onAttach(Activity)` is deprecated from API 23 upwards, instead `onAttach(Context)` is used. `onAttach(Activity)` won't call new `onAttach(Context)` automatically.

So, in order to support all versions of API and to perform attaching actions only once, you have to separate attach logics in a function and call that function from both callbacks performing a check:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    attached();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        attached();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what I did?  So are you saying I didn't miss anything?   Except that your code is cleaner with only one -if- statement.

Comment: Yes, I ended up confirming your thoughts.